# What is the meaning of :*= and :=* operators?

Tags: chisel, rocket-chip

I see some examples in the [RocketChip](https://github.com/freechipsproject/rocket-chip), but could not find info in the [API reference](https://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/api/latest/chisel3/index.html)

```
  masterNode :=* tlOtherMastersNode
  DisableMonitors { implicit p => tlSlaveXbar.node :*= slaveNode }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are not Chisel operators. Instead, they're defined and used by Rocket Chip's `diplomacy` package. These are shorthand operators for doing different types of binding between diplomatic nodes.

No published API documentation for this exists, but you can start poking around in the `diplomacy` package. The releveant location where these are defined is [`src/main/scala/diplomacy/Nodes.scala`](https://github.com/freechipsproject/rocket-chip/blob/master/src/main/scala/diplomacy/Nodes.scala).

Comment: Yeah, Diplomacy, while being a great differentiator of Chisel, is a highly esoteric feature with a poor documentation. We need to add more info about that and publish simple examples beyond Rocket

Comment: Note, that while esoteric, it solves a very real problem: I want to hook up `N` things together and I want their parameters to be a function of what I'm hooking up. Before, this would require very complicated configuration files. Diplomacy makes that far easier, albeit with some complicated software engineering on top of Chisel to enable pre-elaboration actions. If you haven't taken a look at the Diplomacy paper from CARRV 2017, it's a great reference: https://carrv.github.io/2017/papers/cook-diplomacy-carrv2017.pdf.

Answer (score 3):

The [pull request comment](https://github.com/chipsalliance/rocket-chip/pull/536) on this API is very infomative.

Commonly, `A := B` creates a pair of master and slave ports in A and B.
`A :=* B` means the number of port pairs is decided by number of `B := Other`,
and `A :*= B` vice versa.

The most counterintuitive part is that the duplication of links is not achieved by
duplication of the intermediate module, but the intermediate module's expanding of port list.

I have written a simple example to explore star connectors' behavior.

In the following code snippet, an TLIdentifyNode connects 3 TLClientNode using `:=`,
and then it connects to a crossbar node using `:=*` as master to crossbar.
Meanwhile, an TLIdentifyNode connects 2 TLManagerNode using `:=`,
and then it connects to the same crossbar node using `:*=` as salve to crossbar.

```scala
import chisel3._
import chisel3.core.dontTouch
import freechips.rocketchip.config._
import freechips.rocketchip.diplomacy._
import freechips.rocketchip.tilelink._


class ClientConnector(implicit p: Parameters) extends LazyModule {
  val node = TLIdentityNode()
  override lazy val module = new LazyModuleImp(this) {
    (node.in zip node.out) foreach { case ((bundleIn, edgeIn), (bundleOut, edgeOut)) =>
      bundleOut <> bundleIn
    }
  }
}


class ManagerConnector(implicit p: Parameters) extends LazyModule {
  val node = TLIdentityNode()
  override lazy val module = new LazyModuleImp(this) {
    (node.in zip node.out) foreach { case ((bundleIn, edgeIn), (bundleOut, edgeOut)) =>
      bundleOut <> bundleIn
    }
  }
}



class Client(implicit p: Parameters) extends LazyModule {
  val node = TLClientNode(
    portParams = Seq(
      TLClientPortParameters(Seq(
        TLClientParameters("myclient1", IdRange(0, 1), supportsGet = TransferSizes(4), supportsProbe = TransferSizes(4))
      ))
    )
  )

  override lazy val module = new LazyModuleImp(this) {
    node.out.foreach { case(bundle, edge) =>
        val (legal, a) = edge.Get(0.U, 0x1000.U, 2.U)
        bundle.a.bits := a
        bundle.a.valid := legal

        bundle.d.ready := true.B

        dontTouch(bundle)
    }
  }
}


class Manager(base: Int)(implicit p: Parameters) extends LazyModule {
  val node = TLManagerNode(Seq(TLManagerPortParameters(Seq(TLManagerParameters(
    address = Seq(AddressSet(base, 0xffff)),
    supportsGet = TransferSizes(4)
  )), beatBytes = 4)))

  override lazy val module = new LazyModuleImp(this) {
    node.in.foreach { case (bundle, edge) =>
        when (bundle.a.fire()) {
          val d = edge.AccessAck(bundle.a.bits, 0xdeadbeafL.U)
          bundle.d.bits := d
          bundle.d.valid := true.B
        }
        bundle.a.ready := true.B
    }
  }
}


class Playground(implicit p: Parameters) extends LazyModule {

  val xbr               = TLXbar()
  val clientConnectors  = LazyModule(new ClientConnector())
  val managerConnectors = LazyModule(new ManagerConnector())
  val clients           = Seq.fill(3) { LazyModule(new Client()).node }
  val managers          = Seq.tabulate(2) { i: Int => LazyModule(new Manager(0x10000 * i)).node }

  clients.foreach(clientConnectors.node := _)
  managers.foreach(_ := managerConnectors.node)

  managerConnectors.node :*= xbr
  xbr :=* clientConnectors.node

  override lazy val module = new LazyModuleImp(this) {
  }
}
```

The corresponding verilog code of `ManagerConnector` is (in brief):

```
module ManagerConnector(
  `tilelink_bundle(auto_in_0),
  `tilelink_bundle(auto_in_1),
  `tilelink_bundle(auto_out_0),
  `tilelink_bundle(auto_out_1)
);
// ...
endmodule
```

We can see `diplomacy` framework is only responsible for parameter negotiation, port list generation and port connection. The duplication introduced by `*` connection is guaranteed by the common code pattern:

```scala
(node.in zip node.out) foreach { ... }
```

In my opinion, this API simplifies connection between crossbar node and various nodes inside a specific module, and keeps the connection syntax consistent.

[Reference] A rocketchip reading note: https://github.com/cnrv/rocket-chip-read/blob/master/diplomacy/Nodes.md

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful to read the documentation on diplomacy by lowrisc: https://www.lowrisc.org/docs/diplomacy/